# Pass a variable number of arguments to the parent constructor in Node v4

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a class the constructor of which

1. takes a variable number of parameters,
2. passes all its arguments to the parent constructor, and also
3. does some additional initialization.

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        doExtraInit();
    }
}
```

This looks great, and Babel compiles it happily. However, I want to go without Babel and to use just [the ES6 features supported natively by Node](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/). The problem is that Node doesn't parse the code above as it doesn't support the spread operator so far. Is there a way around? Is there something like `super.apply`?

Comment: did you try .apply? that's would i would have tried first.

Comment: Yes, I tried `super.apply(this, arguments)`, but it says `ReferenceError: this is not defined` because it thinks I'm trying to use `this` before calling the parent constructor here.

Comment: It gives me a different error, but it's an error none the less.

Comment: So what's the error for you? BTW, I'm using Node v4.1.0 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: i'm using the chrome console, it's the same error, it just changes based on what you use as the context.

Comment: Interestly enough, chrome already supports the spread operator. Should see what v8 version it's using vs node.js, might be a feature available in the next version.

Comment: I see, you're using [Chrome 46 Beta](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/09/chrome-46-beta-flexible-animations-and.html). Does it work with the spread operator there?

Comment: I'm actually using a 45.x version, and the spread operator works. but, i might have experimental features enabled. I do have experimental features turned on, which means you'd need a harmony flag to get it in node.

Comment: You cannot access `this` before calling `super()`, so yeah, the error is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm leaving this here as a working solution for a transformation: https://gist.github.com/tolmasky/e0b672d0753901bae472 . Was told I should hold off till Babel 6 to pull-request. You can hand-code that today though.

Comment: OMG. Accepting it as strictly speaking, it answers the question. Not sure I'm going to use it though.

Comment: It's strict mode ;) and as far as I can tell the only way to actually accomplish this (without hardcoding in support "up to x arguments"). There's a reason they didn't straight up remove eval in strict mode, on occasion, it has its uses (as opposed to with which was completely removed).

Comment: Please put your answer in your post, not a page linked from it.